# Query for Unique Documents in mongo DB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need a query to copy only unique documents from "A" collection to "B" collection. I shall create an index on "B" collection and then copy the unique documents from "A" to "B" collection.

The "A" collection has almost 3671945 documents.

"A" Collection Mongo DB Document Structure:

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0a91"),
        "aC" : "AN",
        "aI" : "ABCD",
        "aN" : "000000000001",
        "aT" : "AB",
        "pD" : "2022-11-07",
        "transaction" : {
            "seqNo" : 1,
            "tC" : "S"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0a93"),
        "aC" : "AN",
        "aI" : "ABCD",
        "aN" : "000000000001",
        "aT" : "AB",
        "pD" : "2022-11-07",
        "transaction" : {
            "seqNo" : 1,
            "tC" : "S"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0a92"),
        "aC" : "AN",
        "aI" : "ABCD",
        "aN" : "000000000002",
        "aT" : "AB",
        "pD" : "2022-11-08",
        "transaction" : {
            "seqNo" : 2,
            "tC" : "S"
        }
    }
```

Now, I shall create my **primary index** on "B" Collection as follows,

```json
    {
    "aC" : 1,
    "aI" : 1,
    "aN" : 1,
    "aT" : 1,
    "transaction.seqNo" : 1,
    "transaction.tC" : 1,
    "pD" : 1
    }
```

Could you please help me out to query only unique documents from "A" collection to "B" collection based on Index enabled on "B" collection?

Need help on the query .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `$group` with `$first` to pick one document per grouping. Save `$$ROOT` and later replace with the saved `$$ROOT`. Finally use `$merge` to save to collection B.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "aC": "$aC",
        "aI": "$aI",
        "aN": "$aN",
        "aT": "$aT",
        "seqNo": "$transaction.seqNo",
        "tC": "$transaction.tC",
        "pD": "$pD"
      },
      doc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "B",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playgroun](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wCmn6d9j3rM)

A side note: you may want to perform the insertion before creating index to improve the write speed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you want me to copy unique records first from "A" collection to "B" collection and then enable index on "B" collection. @ray

Comment: @Shilpa yes. because index improves read speed with trade of insert speed.